# animating text and image

Tags: android, animation, textview, imageview

i am using frame by frame animation to animate images (imageView). each image has a unique associated text (which i implemeted with textView). is there any way to animate the textView together with imageView?

thanks
lipi

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically create some Layout(i.e RelativeLayout) and add both the imageView and textView in it. Afterwards start the animation on the layout (that's in case you're applying one and the same animation on both of them).

Comment: how do i start the animation for the layout? can the animation list be activated for items other than drawables?

Comment: animations can be started on views. Every Layout inherits from the View class and hence you can start the animation on them. I. if you have TranslateAnimation animation = ... and RelativeLayout layout = ... you start the animation on the layout with layout.startAnimation(TranslateAnimation).

Comment: I meant layout.startAnimation(animation). Can't edit the comment, sorry for the spam.

Comment: Actually i went in a different direction and i will be happy if you can help me figure out the problem.